# Difference tool retains records of deleted point features (without geometry)

Tags: qgis, point, geoprocessing, differences, null-geometry

I was using the Difference tool in QGIS version 3.22 on a points layer with a polygon overlay. This failed. I read this problem is commonly reported in 3.22 and upgraded to 3.30.3, as advised.

Now, on 3.30.3, I can use the tool without error, but I noticed that my output layer has the same amount of features in the attribute table as the input layer (it should have less) in spite of the fact that the the tool clearly worked when looking at the layer itself. It appears it's retaining records of the deleted features in the table but with now invalid geometry.

Any suggestions on how to fix this? Is there a way of filtering the attribute table for invalid geometries and simply deleting them?

Comment: 3.3 is not newer than 3.22 these are [semantic versions](https://semver.org/) not floating point numbers - try 3.28 or 3.30

Comment: In fact, there is no QGIS 3.3 (or just as nightly build) - there are only even version numbers: 3.0, 3.2, 3.4 etc.

Comment: https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html 

"The current versions is 3.30.3..."

Comment: Please edit the correct version number that you have also into the question.

Comment: Surely the difference between 3.30 and 3.3 is not throwing people through a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Solution 1: Delete empty geometries

To get rid of features without geometry, use [`Select by expression`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorselection.html#select-by-expression) with this expression: `$x is NULL`, then delete the selected features.

##### Solution 2: Extract by expression

Even easier, avoiding the difference tool at all, is using Menu <kbd>Processing</kbd> > <kbd>Toolbox</kbd> > [`Extract by expression`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorselection.html#extract-by-expression) with this expression: `overlay_disjoint ('polygon')` applied on your initial point layer (use the name of your polygon layer). Leave the output for `non matching` empty to only get one layer with the matching features.

---

##### *Remark*

*By the way: as of QGIS 3.30, the problem seems to be limted to point geometries. Using line and polygon layers as input layers, features with geometries completely overlapping the polygon overlay are deleted.*